# Select appended item jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would i select the below item, i **do not** want to select every LI of `.top` but just the LI i have just created on the append.

How is this possible?

```
$('.top').append('<li><span>' + html + '</span></li>');
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the [`:last` pseudo-class selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector).

```
$('.top > li:last')
```

---

Alternate option: consider creating the element slightly differently.

```
var $li = $('<li><span>' + html + '</span></li>');
$('.top').append($li);
// you already have the <li> selected, in $li
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matt, this worked more inline with my code with just a simple .find() on the end!

Comment: Thank you so muc, the `:last` makes perfect sense since I want to select the parent and append other elemnts to it inside a loop.

Answer (score 28):

You could do it the other way around using [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo)

```
var li = $('<li><span>' + html + '</span></li>').appendTo('.top');
```

This way you don't have to select it after appending it.

Comment: Using appendTo as described in this answer instead of append+select should have better performance and be 'safer' in regards to be 100% sure to select the right element ...

Comment: Yes, this is the better way to do it, +1

Answer (score 0):

You could probably select the last one:

```
$('.top').last()
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/last/

Comment: That will select the last `.top` matched; whilst reading the question, I assumed that `.top` was a `<ul>`, and the OP wanted to retrieve the `<li>` he had just `append()`ed to `.top`; in which case your code snippet won't work.... or (equally possibly!) I read the question wrong :).

Comment: Ahh, I stand corrected. It was a bit sloppy reading and thinking here.

Comment: Thanks for answer, though i wanted to select the child of .top, the `<li>` element of the `<ul class="top">`